# Inline Nested Lists

Tags: sencha-touch, sencha-touch-2, sencha-architect

How do I do this :
http://try.sencha.com/touch/2.1.0/guides/nested_list.3/

I'm using sencha architect. I don't want to use JSON or XML or whatever. I want it to be inline.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Sencha touch nested list no data](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16161128/sencha-touch-nested-list-no-data)

Answer is there.

I don't know why Sencha team provide a non working exemple with root...